# Solve the integral

Tags: calculus, integration

How does one solve the following integral?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2-x} dx$$

I've tackled this thing every way I can think of and I'm still lost.

Comment: As a side comment - quite often integrals of this nature (not her) can be simplified with Glasser's Master Theorem
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Completing the square can put it into the standard form here with the appropriate substitution.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2-x} dx  = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{1}{4}} dx = e^{\frac{1}{4}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(x+\frac{1}{2})^2} dx$$

See [this question also](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/173861/43193)